# my website doesn't work in firefox - text going beyond margin

Tags: html, css, firefox

I have designed a website to be dynamic so that the width of the browser allows for the content to adjust. However on this specific page, the size of the browser in firefox ONLY is giving me problems:

The text goes beyond it's margins and clashes into the image on firefox when adjusting the screen size. Try it out and let me know. The css is very simple as well.

```css
.nav-phone>a:nth-child(3) {
    background-color: #fbc076;
}

.nav>a:nth-child(3) {
    background-color: #fbc076;
}

.newbox {
    background-color: white;
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
}

.readiblecolumns {
    background-color: white;
}

.readiblecolumns>p {
    line-height: 1;
}

/* Desktop */
@media screen and (min-width: 960px) {

    .newbox {
        height: auto;
        width: 80vw;
    }

    /* Reads Like Newspaper */
    .readiblecolumns {
        width: 80vw;
        padding: 20px;
        -webkit-column-count: 3;
        -moz-column-count: 3;
        column-count: 3;
    }

    .readiblecolumns>p {
        font-size: 100%;
    }

    .profile {
        height: 480px;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
    }

    .profile img {
        height: 100%;
        width: auto;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
    }

}

/* Tablet */
@media screen and (min-width: 520px) and (max-width: 959px) {

    .newbox {
        height: auto;
        width: 80vw;
    }

    .readiblecolumns {
        width: 80vw;
        padding: 20px;
        -webkit-column-count: 2;
        -moz-column-count: 2;
        column-count: 2;
    }

    .readiblecolumns>p {
        font-size: 100%;
    }

    .profile {
        height: 320px;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
    }

    .profile img {
        height: 100%;
        width: auto;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
    }

}

/* Phone */
@media screen and (max-width: 519px) {

    .newbox {
        height: auto;
        width: 90vw;
    }

    .readiblecolumns {
        width: 90vw;
        padding: 15px;
    }
}
```

The html is as follows:

```
<div class="newbox">
    <div class="readiblecolumns">
        <div class="profile">
            <img src="Pictures/MyLife/mypicture.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <p>Miusov, as a man man of breeding and deilcacy, could not but feel some inwrd qualms, when he reached the Father Superior's with Ivan: he felt ashamed of havin lost his temper. He felt that he ought to have disdaimed that despicable wretch, Fyodor Pavlovitch, too much to have been upset by him in Father Zossima's cell, and so to have forgotten himself. "Teh monks were not to blame, in any case," he reflceted, on the steps. "And if they're decent people here (and the Father Superior, I understand, is a nobleman) why not be friendly and courteous withthem? I won't argue, I'll fall in with everything, I'll win them by politness, and show them that I've nothing to do with that Aesop, thta buffoon, that Pierrot, and have merely been takken in over this affair, just as they have."</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please include your code in the shortest format possible *in your question*.  Outsourced links can be outdated and lost, therefore erasing the content in your question.

Comment: it is not outdated nor lost, I worked on the domain earlier today

Comment: @Max The point is: once you correct your website, the question will be completely pointless.

Comment: I uploaded the css, but you could have easily found that on the page, I do not appreciate downvoting my question because it is a serious concern that I do not understand

Comment: Okay I understand @Xufox hopefully someone can take a look at the css now and fix what error I have made

Comment: @Max Again, once you have _corrected_ it “on the page”, _the relevant CSS will no longer be_ “on the page”, thus making your question useless for future visitors.

Comment: @Xufox do you understand the problem now?

Answer (score 0):

It has to do with `.profile{width:480px;}`, then making the `.profile img{height:100%; width:auto;}`. When the Browser size changes width, the image is still base on the 100% height of `.profile` (which may not have changed at all), therefore it's not scaling the way you desire. Your image should really fit the original page load design for vector scaling, anyways. Give `.profile` the proper height and width, then you can set `.profile img{height:100%; width:100%;}`.